# Get value from an array from a URL

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a url, `http://btcrate.com/convert?from=btc&to=usd&exch=mtgox&conv=xe&amount=0.01`, which outputs `{"converted": "1.300000300"}`. I want to get the value of converted into a PHP value, so `$usd = 1.300000300;`.

I have tried the following, but it just outputs the whole string, although I just want the value of converted.

```
file_get_contents("http://btcrate.com/convert?from=btc&to=usd&exch=mtgox&conv=xe&amount=0.01");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data being returned is in `JSON` format, so you can decode the `JSON` and then simply retrieve the value of `converted`

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://btcrate.com/convert?from=btc&to=usd&exch=mtgox&conv=xe&amount=0.01");

$obj = json_decode($data );
$converted = $obj->{'converted'};

echo $converted;
```

[*Learn more about using JSON in PHP here*](http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use arrays:

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://btcrate.com/convert?from=btc&to=usd&exch=mtgox&conv=xe&amount=0.01");

$result = json_decode($string, true);
$converted = $result['converted'];

echo $converted;
```